# JQuery UI - Cannot change month/year in datepicker within Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Using **Datepicker** inside a **modal Dialog**, don't work the **Change Month/Year** dropdown in Firefox 19.0.2 see:

http://jsfiddle.net/469zV/2/
**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="test" style="display:none">
  <form>
     <fieldset>
        <p>Date1: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>  
     </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    modal: true
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

After search a lot can find some info about this problem but nothing about solution:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8989#no1

How do I solve this?

Comment: It seems the modal box focuses the datepicker input. Try $("#datepicker").blur(); in the dialog open event listener.

Comment: @Ian Brindley Thanks for help but don't work

Comment: Faced same issue with colorbox popup.
Finally got the solutions https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you were looking for, but if you drop the text input, it will give you the month and year selection back.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/469zV/45/)**

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({  
    modal:true,
    height:340,
    width:340
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

});

<div id="dialog-form" title="test" style="display:none"> 
    <form>
    <fieldset> 
        <div id="datepicker"/></div>  
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to blur out of the textbox after picking a date so it can re-trigger the focus event:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    modal: true
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true    
}).on('change',function(){
                 $(this).blur()
               });
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me: 
$(document).unbind('focusin');

Answer (score 0):

This is causing may be for using ui and bootstrap.js both. 
The class `modal-open` that is adding in body tag have an property of `overflow-y:hiiden`. You need to omit that property and the datepicker year change will work

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Ui Datepicker month/year dropdown is not working in popup in latest firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887850/jquery-ui-datepicker-month-year-dropdown-is-not-working-in-popup-in-latest-firef?rq=1)

Add this code to your javascript script or file.

```
    var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
    $confModal.on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
    });
    $confModal.modal({ backdrop : false });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
    uidp = $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('forced-display-none').detach();
    $(el).parent().append(uidp);
    setTimeout(function(){$(uidp).css({'position':'relative','left':'0px','top':'0px'}).removeClass('forced-display-none')},200);
}
```

or if you wish to use fixed position:

```
beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
    c = $(el).closest("div.modal-dialog");
    if ($(c).length) {
        l = $(el).offset().left - $(c).offset().left;
        t = $(el).offset().top - $(c).offset().top; //$(el).height();
        uidp = $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('forced-display-none').detach();
        $(el).parent().append(uidp);
        setTimeout(function(){$(uidp).css({'position':'fixed','left':l+'px','top':t+'px'}).removeClass('forced-display-none')},150);
    }
}
```

define forced-display-none as:

```
.forced-display-none {display: none !important;}
```