# Jquery Ui Datepicker month/year dropdown is not working in popup in latest firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

Somehow my jQuery UI Datepicker Month/Year Dropdown not working in any popup in latest firefox .

When I click on Month or Year Dropdown, the options list doesn't appears.

Here is my Popup & Datepicker Code:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    modal: true
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

I prepared a demo on JSfiddle too:

http://jsfiddle.net/469zV/2/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because the modal enforces focus on itself. Here is a solution for this as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error/19190216#19190216) . Add the below script to your js file. That's it.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/93eTU/16/

Ref: [Twitter bootstrap multiple modal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649459/twitter-bootstrap-multiple-modal-error/19190216#19190216)

```
// Since confModal is essentially a nested modal it's enforceFocus method
// must be no-op'd or the following error results 
// "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
// But then when the nested modal is hidden we reset modal.enforceFocus
var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

$confModal.on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = enforceModalFocusFn;
});

$confModal.modal({ backdrop : false });
```

**For Bootstrap 4:**

```
replace : $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus
By: $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus
```

Comment: I also get the problem even though I don't use bootstrap. Any idea on how to solve it? jQuery v1.12.4 and jQuery UI v1.12.1

Comment: this gives me `TypeError: $.fn.modal is undefined`

Answer (score 18):

I had to use

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
$(document)
  .off('focusin.bs.modal') // guard against infinite focus loop
  .on('focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
    if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length) {
      this.$element.focus()
    }
  }, this))
}
```

in order to restrict focus inside model when we use Tab to focus elements (Got from GIT).

tried this>>

```
$("#dateOfBirth").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $(document).off('focusin.bs.modal');
    },
    onClose:function(){
        $(document).on('focusin.bs.modal');
    },
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange : '-150:+0'
});
```

Now I can select the year :)

Comment: it saved my time :)

Comment: glad that it helped :)

Comment: Recently tried FF, and didn't know, the datepicker wouldn't change months/year in FF,
but this solution, _(the second part)_ worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 3):

Ideal solution is to move date picker popup div inside modal dialog.

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
          $(el).parent().append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
          $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
        }    
    }
});
```

**Note**: Will have to update css a bit. Check jsfiddle link for actual demo.

**JsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/469zV/414/

Comment: In my case, this solution works, but it interferes the other datepicker that is outside the dialog. Somehow, I can't open that other datepicker anymore after I open the one inside modal dialog.

Comment: In this case you need to be selective while applying the change like, `$("#datepicker.your-special-class").datepicker({ beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
          $(el).parent().append($('#ui-datepicker-div.your-special-class'));
          $('#ui-datepicker-div.your-special-class').hide();
        }`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Somehow, `$('#ui-datepicker-div.your-special-class')` doesn't exist. Even though I have set the `your-special-class` class to my datepicker input.

Comment: I have also tried it with your provided JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vdpgf3jm/1/

Answer (score 1):

**Magnific popup with jquery ui datepicker (changemonth and changeyear is enabled)**

*Try this code*

```
// Added to make calendar drop downs work properly
$.magnificPopup.instance._onFocusIn = function(e) {

    if( $(e.target).hasClass('ui-datepicker-month') ) {
        return true;
    }
    if( $(e.target).hasClass('ui-datepicker-year') ) {
        return true;
    }
    $.magnificPopup.proto._onFocusIn.call(this,e);
};
```

Comment: where should i put this? Inside magnificPopup() function callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

In modern times -- 2018, with Bootstrap 4.1 -- I was able to solve this by simply passing `focus : false` to the modal constructor.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
    uidp = $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('forced-display-none').detach();
    $(el).parent().append(uidp);
    setTimeout(function(){$(uidp).css({'position':'relative','left':'0px','top':'0px'}).removeClass('forced-display-none')},200);
}
```

define forced-display-none as:

```
.forced-display-none {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I give a solution for jquery daterangepicker nested in bootstrap modal (problem: selectors month/years not appearing on FF browser). The solution is to add the "parentEl" option indicating the modal in which the daterangepicker is to be initialized:

```
 $('#example-date-input').daterangepicker({
            parentEl: $('.modal-where-daterangepicker-should-be-nested'),
            .....
 });
```

Comment: This code works in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I believed the datepicker was failing, but what really happen was that a previously referenced datepicker (bootstrap-datepicker.js) was taken precedence over the jquery-ui datepicker.