# How to fix month / year combobox in datepicker inside a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use a datepicker inside a modal. But, I can't change the month/year in the datepicker.

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797893/jquery-ui-cannot-change-month-year-in-datepicker-within-modal-dialog). But the selected answer is not the one I'm looking for.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/469zV/2/) based on the above question.

My html:

`<input type="text" id="sel_periode_1" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />`

Comment: Hey, you have put date picker in modal right?

Comment: yes. I put the datepicker inside the modal

Comment: you can share your code otherwise i will put my own code.

Comment: you can answer by your own code. my jquery is the same in the fiddle

Comment: Try my code i hope this will be work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem I can't select themonth/year beacuse I use `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

My solution is to change it into `$('#myModal').fadeIn('fast');`

Comment: I've voted but when I checked in real situation it's not working as expected. cause when you lunch a modal using fadeIn the dismiss will not work

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
   <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
          <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text"></input>
          <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your input as follows,

```
<input type="text" id="sel_periode_1" readonly="readonly" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

add following code to your script,

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
                // set properties as your requirement
 });
```

Note: add reference to `jquery.min.js`,`jquery-ui.min.js` and `jquery-ui.css` for the `datepicker` to work.

[Fiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/exAMc/577/)

Comment: Your code will work fine, but it's not the case. cause you don't use: $('.modal').modal('show');